# Android : modifying Bluetooth configuration from code

Tags: android, android-intent, configuration, bluetooth, visibility

I would like to know if there's a way to modify Android configuration with my app (with appropriate right in manifest).

My problem is to put Bluetooth visibility to "always" (in Params -> BlueTooth -> Visibility delay -> Always). The code "Intent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 0);" is locked by the default configuration in Android. If the user choose "2 min" in Android, the previous code will unlock visibility for only 2 minutes...

Any clue?